# How do certain websites create new pages when you submit a post/video?

Tags: php, mysql, web

Websites like **reddit**, **youtube**, **quora** and even **stackoverflow** create a new page for every new question/post/video that users submit/upload. How do they do that? I'm expecting they use php and MySQL. Could somebody roughly tell me how it's done?

An example would be this question that I now asked.

> stackoverflow.com/questions/**51026958**/**how-do-certain-websites-create-new-pages-when-you-submit-a-post-video**

Shortly: How do i create an unique url for every post with php and mysql on my website?

Comment: The magic is behind the data which is stored in the db and the front-end templates that are used to show the data

Comment: *"I'm expecting they use php and MySQL."* could be ... or one of dozens of other server-side language + database combinations.

Comment: Those are not necessarily new pages, just new URL's which are just a link they provide pointing to a resource.  The page is generated on the fly for your content stored in a datastore and a response is generated on that URL, no 'page' needs be created, per se.

Comment: They use a technic called `URL rewriting` or `SEO url` in a .htaccess file or application code to add to @BrandonSørenCulley 's comment

Comment: @RaymondNijland More generically it's having a "routing layer" between the URI and the code and/or content that's linked to it.

Comment: Do you know any tutorials about url rewriting?

Comment: "More generically it's having a "routing layer" between the URI and the code and/or content that's linked to it." true @tadman i know that i maked it more searchable on Google for the topicstarter by giving him some terms..

Comment: "Do you know any tutorials about url rewriting? " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php  very basic example

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) and [Laravel](http://laravel.com/), among others, and they handle this by introducing an abstraction between the URL and the content.

That is, the URL no longer represents a particular asset or script on your filesystem, but a more abstract concept of a *resource*.

Legacy PHP applications have paths that look like:

```
/users/info.php?id=2
```

A modern application will describe this differently:

```
/users/2/info
```

Where that path has data encoded in it that can be extracted and utilized by your [MVC layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

You can see how this works in practice by [using Laravel as an example](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing).

It's worth noting that these routed URLs are a lot cleaner, there's less technical cruft in them, and the back-end you're using can change completely without having to fake it or break links.